# Checking whether a python function arguments have value or not

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python function with multiple arguments. The way that the function works depends on whether arguments set to value or not. How can I check if a python function argument has value?

Comment: If the argument has no value, it's undefined, and the call will fail.  Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  Perhaps a function with default values for the **parameters**?

Comment: Could you just set default value to certain arguments and if those default values persist then you know there is no "real" value set to them.

Comment: Similar to what @Prune was saying you could use a try/except block.  Try to call an argument, if it works great.  If not then you catch the exception and move on.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python function default argument", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  Voted to close.

Comment: A defined function argument in Python always has a value, either given in the call or a default value. If both is not true an exception will be raised.

Comment: I guess OP is missing "function overloading" from C++ (or similar concept from other language) and want to emulate it in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
def func(par1=None):
    if par1 is None:
        #you got function without parameters
        print("No parameter")
    else:
        print(par1)
>>func()
<<No parameter
>>func('Hi')
<<Hi
```

Comment: `None` is a singleton in Python and the best way to test is `par1 is None` instead of `part1 == None`.

Comment: pardon,i just mixed some programming langauges XD

Answer (score 0):

You can assign default values to python arguments like so:

```
def example(eg1="Value here", eg2=2):
    print(eg1)
    print(eg2)
```

will then output "Value here" and 2 respectively when example is called, like so:

example()

Let me know if this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to stick with keyword arguments, you can do something like this:

```
VALID_ARGUMENTS = ('foo', 'bar', 'cheese', 'eggs', 'spam')

def multiple_dispatch_named(**kwargs):
    for argument_name in kwargs:
        if argument_name not in VALID_ARGUMENTS:
            raise TypeError(
                f"argument_name() got an unexpected keyword argument '{argument_name}'")

    if 'cheese' not in kwargs:
        raise TypeError(f"argument_name() missing the required 'cheese'")

    if 'foo' in kwargs:
        return do_some_foo_with(**kwargs)

    if 'bar' in kwargs:
        return do_some_bar_with(**kwargs)

    return do_some_default_with(**kwargs)
```